# How to select only first element in cascade?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3kjt5me/1/). How to select only first span without using $('div > span')?

```
<div>
    <span>
        Only this span needs to be selected
        <div>
            <span>1</span>
            <span>2</span>
            <span>3</span>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not valid to have `span>div` in your document tree.

Comment: Try `div span:first-child`.

Comment: There's not enough context here to answer your question. What other markup is in the page that's available as selectors? What's the reason for your stated limitation?

Comment: `span:first-child {}` or `span:nth-child(1) {}`

Comment: @saNs, APAD1: both your examples would select two elements in this case.

Comment: first-child selects spans in div, but I want to select only top-level span WITHOUT div :)

Comment: Now you're asking two questions--how to select a particular element, and how to select only its text content. Please clarify *in your question above*.

Comment: Text content it's example. I need to select particular element.

Comment: with JQuery, you can use the .eq(index) method ( http://api.jquery.com/eq/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div').children('span').eq(0);
// or
$('div').find('span:first-child');
```

etc